# Negotiating a salary after internship?

Tags: salary, internship, student, first-job

I was an intern this summer and have been offered to continue working there part-time during the school year. I have a meeting coming up to discuss the details...however I have been talking to some people and have been told I should negotiate salary.

I got paid quite well for being an intern and am happy with what I make (if I worked full time I would make 50K a year for perspective) so not crazy amazing, but fair for an intern. However, reading online, it seems like its important to set a tone early on. I don't want to not negotiate a salary and then be considered less than valuable especially if I continue with the company once I graduate.

However, I feel super awkward and unsure whether I am being greedy since so many people would love to take my job, especially with the job market being awful...but I don't want to be meek and a pushover.

Please help me with your opinions and experience!

Comment: How old are you and whích continent? 50K a year sounds amazing. Unless the currency is like Yen.

Comment: Its in dollars and I am my last year in college. Its a fair salary, I expect if I am a full-time employee as entry level they pay around 80K a year with benefits. So its a fair salary and may be less elsewhere, not entirely sure the average or where to find that. I should be clear, I am not unhappy with pay, but unsure if I don't say something now and fight for myself I am settling for less and looking meek.

Comment: thats 72.000 euro, I am living on the wrong continent...

Answer (score 4):

The single biggest question you have to ask yourself is, "What am I prepared to work for?"

If the offered salary is satisfactory to you, then there's no point negotiating.  However, if you feel that it's not in line with your skills and experience, *then* you can negotiate.  You will want to back it up with some research, such as average graduate salaries in your area.  You do have the additional advantage of having interned there and therefore background domain knowledge of the organisation.

I certainly would *not* be negotiating for the sake of negotiating.  Decide if you are satisfied with their offer, and either accept, reject or negotiate.